# How to run multiple activities and also close those activities

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I have an activity in which the user enters the no of items to be created.
I have created an activity to enter the details of the item.
After pressing a button then the activity for entering details starts

For more than one item the activity should run one after the other and if the user presses back button a popup arises to confirm cancel the process.

I wrote in Kotlin language

I tried by using for loop but all the activities run in the background, I should press back button for all the activity

Comment: Simple solution, use fragments and not activities for this task.

Comment: Thank you for your support but can you provide me with some link to learn about it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ViewPager` in your activity and a adapt a list of fragments for each item using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The backstack will contain only the fragment holding the `ViewPager` so presing back will close the activity alltogheter.

Main Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private MyFragmentAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.setFragments("5");
        myViewPager = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Fragment Adapter :

```
class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void setFragments(String noOfFragments){
        int intFragments = Integer.parseInt(noOfFragments);
        for (int i = 0; i < intFragments; i++){
            this.fragments.add(new Fragment());
        }
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"enter code here>

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

- I have removed the views qualifiers, you should fill in with either support library or androidx

Comment: I am a beginner to programming so I don't know much about fragment kindly help me how to write such code

Comment: @ShafiqurRahman I've updated my answer with an example.You can take your input from EditText and plug it in the adapter.

Comment: As it is in Java language I will try myself to write in Kotlin and will update the result

Comment: @ShafiqurRahman Seeing that you are using Kotlin, I will guess you are using androidx dependecie so xml tags should look like this: `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>`

Comment: There is a null pointer exception for the following : myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Could you supply the stack trace?